# C# Application.Run - Close Open File

Tags: c#

I have created a program to run on all of my users computers. 
When the application is launched from my server (\\fs3\netlogon\app.exe) it stays open throughout the lifetime of the program. I identify this by seeing it as an "open file" in Computer Management.
I can force the "open file" to close from Computer Management and the program still runs fine.

```
public partial class Primary : Form { *my code* }

Process[] procList = Process.GetProcessesByName(programName);

        if (Process.GetProcessesByName(programName).Length == 1)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Primary());
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName(programName))
            {
                if (Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id != p.Id)
                {
                    p.CloseMainWindow();
                    p.Close();
                    p.Kill();
                    p.Dispose();
                }
            }
            Main();
```

[Example of many instances of the file loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpToi.png)

Before I go ahead and spend the time to develop an entirely new method I wanted to ask to see if I make my current format work.

My goal is to launch the app, close the "open file" and the app continues to run no problem.

This is likely a misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: Are you explicitly opening the filestream in code?...or is this a side effect of running your app?

Comment: It is a misunderstanding, it is not a FileStream.  You are seeing the side-effect of the memory-mapped view the CLR uses to load an assembly.  Forcing the file to close is liable to crash the app when the just-in-time compiler needs to generate more code.   ClickOnce deployment is the other way to do it, keeps the view open on a local copy of the assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You're not explicitly closing the current instance if you find an existing one.

```
   if (Process.GetProcessesByName(programName).Length == 1)
   {   
       Application.EnableVisualStyles();
       Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
       Application.Run(new Primary());
   }
   else
   {
       Application.Shutdown();
   }
```

Edited: fixed reasoning and solution

Comment: Wouldn't you want to check that `GetProssesesBYName` returns anything before wrapping it in a using statement? Or at least check for null before the length?

Comment: GetProssesesBYName returns an array of zero or more objects. The using statement will never fail.

Comment: Alright. I wasn't sure if it did or not. A good note to have I suppose.

Comment: Mea culpa, read the wrong section in the docs, try the above.

Comment: I uploaded the code I use to handle if a process is already found to be running. This solution doesn't resolve my problem.

Comment: Why the call to Main()? You should only have 1 or 2 instances of the application running (well, you could have more than two if you launch them quickly enough). If you have one (this current instance) then you create the form etc. If you have 2 then you close this instance. No messing about killing other processes.

Comment: The idea is to kill all processes and reopen, I could call Application.Run() but it has the same result if I just call Main(). I will take that into consideration, I have been considering whether I go for kill or close. But whether I kill or close doesn't resolve my main issue of it keeping an open file on after I launch the program.